# Precise definition of limits

Tags: limits

Prove using only the precise definition of limits that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x->1^+} \sqrt{x^3-1} = 0
\end{align}
I can't seem to find a way to express $|\sqrt{x^3-1}|$ in terms of $|x-1|$ and hence I was not able to form any inequalities to prove this question. Please assist

Comment: You don't need to worry about absolute value signs as x > 1.

Answer (score 2):

If $|x-1| < \delta < 1$ and $x > 1$, then $x < 1 + \delta < 2$ and we have

$$|x^3 - 1| = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1) < \delta\bigl((1+\delta)^2 + (1+\delta) + 1\bigr) < \delta(2^2 + 2 + 1) = 7\delta.$$

Thus for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can choose $\delta < \varepsilon^2/7$ and we get

$$\left| \sqrt{x^3-1} - 0 \right| =  \sqrt{x^3-1} < \sqrt{7\delta} < \sqrt{\varepsilon^2} = \varepsilon.$$

Therefore, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^+} \sqrt{x^3-1} =0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $\epsilon >0$ and $x >1$

Let $1 > \delta > 0$

Then $x -1 < \delta $ means

$1 < x < 1 + \delta $

$1 < x^3 < 1 + 3\delta + 3\delta^2  + \delta^3 < 1 + 7\delta$

$0 < x^3 - 1 < 7\delta $

$0 < \sqrt{x^3-1} < \sqrt {7\delta}$

So for $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta =\min (1, \epsilon^2/7) $.

Then $|x -1| < \delta \implies |\sqrt {x^3 - 1} -0| < \epsilon $

As $x>1$ we don't have to worry about absolute values.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work.

Comment: Okay, now it will.

Comment: Useful fact that $b^n - 1 \ge n (b-1) $... oh ARGGGH!  still won't work....

Comment: Argh after all the editing my answer turns out to be exactly the same as the other.  I'll delete it in the morning.  (My original idea was to note $e^2 +1 < (e^3/2 + 1)^3$... and then I realized the inequality worked against me.... sigh)